# Setting the Header of GroupBox in a GroupBox style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, header, groupbox

I'm getting XAML parse exceptions when using a certain `GroupBox` Style more than once. I'm keeping the style in `UserControl.Resources`.

Here is an example of a simplified style that *does not* cause a XAML parse exception:

```
<Style x:Key="MyGroupBoxStyle" TargetType="GroupBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type GroupBox}}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="Hello World!" />
</Style>
```

Here is another one that *does not* cause a problem.

```
<Style x:Key="MyGroupBoxStyle" TargetType="GroupBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type GroupBox}}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="Header">
        <Setter.Value>
            Hello World!
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This one however *does* cause a problem:

```
<Style x:Key="MyGroupBoxStyle" TargetType="GroupBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type GroupBox}}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="Header">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World!" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Again, it's only a problem when I use the style on *more than one* `GroupBox`. If I use it just once, I don't get the XAML parse exception.  And it doesn't have to be just a `TextBlock`. I think it's any `UIElement`.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Not quite sure, but BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type GroupBox}}" seems wrong to me. Try it without this.

Comment: Still doesn't work when removing the `BasedOn`. Using `BasedOn` in that manner allows me to continue using a previously defined generic `Style` for `GroupBox`es.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the content of the header to another UI control in the style. Try creating a datatemplate.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyGroupBoxStyle" TargetType="GroupBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type GroupBox}}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="Hello World!!!!!!"/>
                </DataTemplate>                    
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <GroupBox Style="{StaticResource MyGroupBoxStyle}" Height="200" Width="200"/>
    <GroupBox Style="{StaticResource MyGroupBoxStyle}" Height="200" Width="200"/>
</StackPanel>
```